# Change post url

Tags: wordpress

I have a Web page that has a blog. It has a static home page, and you can access the menu using the top menu.

When I visit my site, it looks like:

> www.mysite.com

When I go to my blog, it looks like:

> www.mysite.com/blog

But when I visit a post, it looks like:

> www.mysite.com/my-post-name.html

And I want it to look:

> www.mysite.com/blog/my-post-name.html

How can I achieve this? Is there any way without plugins? Or maybe, any plugin that won't crash anything?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the [Permalink Settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen),

Comment: I love you!! :DD Could you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change this in the [Permalink Settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen):

In "Custom Structure", enter `/blog/%postname%/` (or `/blog/%postname%.html`).